# Using C# to send values to Java application

Tags: c#, java

I have developed a Java application. This application basically requires a string named "input" to process. After that string is given to this program, returns "yes" or "no" depends on string.

I also have a C# application. This c# application returns a string named "result". I want to use that "result" as "input" for my Java application. Then return Java's returning value("yes" or "no") to C#. How can I do that? How can i create a connection between those programs? I don't want to use any web service for that.

I am using Eclipse for Java, and Visual Studio for C#.

I would appreciate your help.

Thank you!

(Edited)Extra information:

C# application is form applcation and has an visual interface and converts XML(which is given by user) to string, and it should pass it to Java. Java application is console application and checks that if string is correct in some terms. Both programs are in the same machine. I prefer not to use any online server or something like that.

Comment: Write a file first :)
Read that file after :). Or use webservices. Or named pipes: http://v01ver-howto.blogspot.it/2010/04/howto-use-named-pipes-to-communicate.html

Comment: You can look at Interprocess Communication. There is alot of way to do that. @br1 mentionned, you can use named pipe, WCF, ...

Comment: First of all thanks for answer. What do you mean by write a file? There are lots of data transaction between those programs, not just a string :) I wanted to give an example.

Comment: Are both programs running on the same machine? Are they console apps, or web pages?

Comment: Yes same machine with Windows operating system. Java is console app, c# is form application.

Comment: Yup! Anyway, it's not an easy answer to give, since there's a huuuge iceberg under the point you're seeing.

Comment: C# program has an visual interface and converts XML(which is given by user) file to string, and it should pass it to Java. Java program checks that if string is correct in some terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Java app is a console app; then call create an instance the application with System.Diagnostics.Process and redirect the input and output streams.

Something like this:

```
var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo { RedirectStandardInput = true, RedirectStandardOutput = true, FileName = "javaapp.exe" });
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("Hello");
var response = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thanks man, it helped really much. I will try that once i get to work. My regards.

Comment: Mate I only typed that out quickly so make sure you refer to MSDN on how to use the input and output streams correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In your C# form, you could do this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(foo, bar);
```

Where `foo` is the complete path to the Java application, and `bar` is the value of result. This is the programatic equivalent of calling an app in the prompt with parameters. In other words, this is the same as opening the prompt and typing:

> c:\> foo bar

If your program is not using a wrapper exe, then you might want to open Java.exe instead - just tweak what you pass to the `Start` method.

Comment: Hey there thanks for answer. I will try that. But i have some questions:
bar is the "result" that i recieve from c# program and provide to java app? 
Also doing this in C# only is enough or do i need to add any lines of code to java too?
And as last of my questions, how can i recieve "yes" or "no" values from java and transfer them to c#?

Comment: In respective order: yes, the `bar` there is the result; no, you shouldn't have to add any code in Java, if it already works via prompt; and I'm really sorry, but I couldn't code in Java to save my life. I know how to pass data to Java because it's a console app. In order to pass data back to a windows form, refer to the techniques people have suggested in the question comments.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be using a basic TCP connection if you google this there are many examples.

For C# concider:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1415/Introduction-to-TCP-client-server-in-C

And for Java

http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/

Comment: Hey thanks for answer but i prefer not to use web protocols for that purpose.